# PHP OO DB Connection

Tags: php, mysql, database

what is the role/purpose of the line:

```
$db->next_result();
```

If I remove the line I get the same output/result.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if ($result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users`")) {
    printf("Successfully queried.\n");
}

if($result){

    while ($row=$result->fetch_object()){
        print_r($row);
    }

    // Free result set
    $result->close();
    $db->next_result();

}

else echo($db->error);

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: here since in your case there is only one query .there will be no effect .actually it Prepares next result set from a previous call to mysqli_multi_query()..also you need to read docs they tell a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from `php` docs

```
mysqli::next_result -- mysqli_next_result — Prepare next result from multi_query
```

Comment: am I confusing row with result?

Comment: When you use multiple query at that time use `next_result` to get the result of next query.